# Let switch-to-buffer to already open buffer switch to that window, rather than open it in this one

Tags: buffers, window, window-splitting

Is there a way to make switch-to-buffer more dwim in this regard? Let's say I have two windows with foo.el and bar.el open. With my point in foo.el, if I switch-to-buffer and open bar.el, I'd like to just be taken to the other window, rather than be left with two windows of bar.el.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```el
(defun my-switch-to-buffer (buffer)
  "Display BUFFER in the selected window.
If BUFFER is displayed in an existing window, select that window instead."
  (interactive
   (list (get-buffer (read-buffer
                      "Switch to buffer: "
                      (other-buffer (current-buffer))))))
  (if-let ((win (get-buffer-window buffer)))
      (select-window win)
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)))
```

---

Update: while defining a new command is a clear and clean solution, advising `switch-to-buffer` will make `switch-to-buffer` and other commands which call `switch-to-buffer` (such as `ido-switch-buffer` and `helm-buffers-list`) have the new behavior.

```el
(defun switch-to-buffer--hack (orig-fun &rest args)
  (if-let ((win (get-buffer-window (car args))))
      (select-window win)
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'switch-to-buffer :around #'switch-to-buffer--hack)
```

(This doesn't work with Ivy's `ivy-switch-buffer` for some reason)

Comment: Is it possible to do this as an advice, to make it more general? What if no matter the function used to select the buffer, I could apply this logic?

Comment: Sounds like very reasonable request! I will update my answer soon for this.

Comment: @xuchunyang Maybe you can use `get-buffer-window` to get rid of the `dolist` loop?

Comment: @cutejumper I didn't know about it. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Thanks for the update. `(advice-add 'ivy--switch-buffer-action :around #'switch-to-buffer--hack)` lets it also work with ivy-switch-buffer :)

Comment: Using advice with `switch-to-buffer` seems to automatically work for `ivy-switch-buffer` now.