# switch to dedicated window instead of duplicating the buffer

Tags: buffers, frames, dedicated-windows

I can make a buffer dedicated to a frame using the following snippet I got from other posts

```
(defun toggle-window-dedicated ()
  "Toggle whether the current active window is dedicated or not"
  (interactive)
  (message
   (if (let (window (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)))
     (set-window-dedicated-p window (not (window-dedicated-p window))))
       "Window '%s' is dedicated"
     "Window '%s' is normal")
   (current-buffer)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'toggle-window-dedicated)
```

Now from from another frame if I want to switch to the dedicated buffer then a copy of the buffer is opened. This is not the behavior I want. I want the focus to switch to the dedicated frame. 
The solution posted here : [switch-to-buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21149/let-switch-to-buffer-to-already-open-buffer-switch-to-that-window-rather-than-o) does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to switch to a buffer that is in another frame, use **`C-x 5 b`**, not `C-x 4 b` or `C-x b`.  IOW, just use `C-x 5 b` for your buffer that is in a dedicated window, after using your toggle command.
2. If you want to have certain buffers *always* be in dedicated windows in their own frames, you can use option **`special-display-buffer-names`** or **`special-display-regexps`**.

   For example, if you customize `special-display-buffer-names` to be `(("foo.el"))` then whenever you use a command that displays buffer `foo.el` it is shown in its own frame, in a dedicated window.

   (Personally, I set `special-display-regexps` to `("[ ]?[*][^*]+[*]")`, so all buffers with names matching `*...*` are in dedicated windows in their own frames.)

   [If you prefer to mess with `display-buffer-alist` instead, be my guest and have fun.  Emacs insists that `special-display-(regexps|buffer-names)` are obsolete. But thankfully they still work fine.  Hopefully they will always continue to work fine.]

Comment: :). Thanks for the C-x 5 b tip. I guess the question now is it possible to still use C-x b but it redirects to C-x  5 b for dedicated windows. I will look more into special-display-regexps (is a neat approach) and display-buffer-alist. My emacs fu is not up to par yet but hope to be their soon.

Comment: See #2 above. If you do that then `C-x b` automatically does what you are asking.

Comment: I know what I have to do but I don't how to achieve that in the code base above. Specifically,  the elisp directive should be 

(setq special-display-buffer-names (current-buffer)) where current-buffer is obtained as shown in the above snippet. I need to figure how to chain this directive with the above snippet.

Comment: No. `current-buffer` returns a buffer, not a buffer name (a string). If you don't know the names of the buffers that you want to make `special-display` and you don't know even a pattern (regexp) that all of their names will match, then you cannot use the two options I mentioned. You'll perhaps have to wrestle with using `display-buffer-alist`.


And what I said was not intended as something to do to your `toggle-*` code. It was a response to your question about to make a given buffer have a dedicated window and then switch to it in its own frame.